# struct with most special members defaulted except `constexpr A& operator=(A&& rhs)` fails to compile

Tags: c++

Why does this c++ code fail to compile? It's a simple struct with all the special member functions except basic ctors defaulted except for the rref assignment operator when implemented with a simple `std::swap` Note that it works fine if the copy assignment is defaulted. I can't figure out what the difference is.

Also, the MSVC compiler errors out with a constexpr recursion limit.

```
failure was caused by evaluation exceeding call depth limit of 512 (/constexpr:depth<NUMBER>)
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jGK6hbxco

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{
    int i;
    std::string s;
    constexpr A() : i(0), s{ "12345678901234567890" } {}
    constexpr A(int ii) : i(ii), s{ "12345678901234567890" } {}
    constexpr A(const A&) = default;
    constexpr A(A&&) = default;
    constexpr A& operator=(const A&) = default;
    constexpr A& operator=(A&& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr ~A() = default;
};

constexpr int foo()
{
    A i0(0);    // call ctor
    i0 = A(3);  // call assign ctor
    return i0.i;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int i = foo();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Try individually swapping the elements.  `std::swap(i, rhs.i);`  `std::swap(s, rhs.s);`

Comment: Does the code run without all the `constexpr`s?

Comment: Looks like infinite recursion at the swaps.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, it runs fine without constexpr. Using constexpr to validate no UB. Oddly, it also works fine if `i` and `s` are const ints and strings. Go figure.

Comment: Pretty sure it'll blow up. Looks like `swap` will call `=` which will call `swap` which will call `=`, which will yadda yadda yadda...

Comment: @Joe, I'd build that up with an explanation and formalize that comment into an answer

Comment: @Joe. Yep. looks like swapping individual elements works. Makes sense if swap is calling the assignment ctor. Had been using `construct_at` and `destroy_at` which also works and thought swap might be simpler. No idea why it works w/o the constexprs. Weird.

Comment: You don't supply a `swap` function.  The `std::swap` will do the `A tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp;` dance.  Infinite recursion.

Comment: Just checked without the constexprs and it also inf recurses. Not sure what configuration I tested that indicated it worked w/o constexpr. It doesn't.

Comment: It works because of what @user4581301 mentioned.  It's infinite recursion otherwise